# Sort order Dictionary with Arrays iPad 2 vs iPad Air 2. Why reversed?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, ipad, air

I had a failing test on iPad Air 2 but it worked on iPad 2 and I couldn't figure it out.

I started a new project and now I can see the difference.

If I create an Dictionary with arrays:

```
let test = ["header1":["test1"],"header2":["test2"]]
print(test)
```

The result on iPad Air 2 will be:

```
["header2": ["test2"], "header1": ["test1"]]
```

But on iPad 2 it will be:

```
["header1": ["test1"], "header2": ["test2"]]
```

Why is it reversed on iPad Air 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  create a Dictionary,key is `String` value is `Array<String>`,

and **Dictionary is not a ordered collection**

If you want data in order,you should use `Array`

[image]

Comment: So basically I have to order it?

Comment: If you need order,consider using `Array`,if using Dictionary,you should not care the oder

Comment: Stupid of me not to think about that. What confused me is that it was "ordered" the same on each device every time.

Answer (score 2):

You're not creating an Array of Arrays, you're creating a Dictionary (of type `[String: Array]`) with keys `header1` and `header2`.

Dictionaries are not ordered.